# Returning an interface with interface type argument

Tags: java, generics

I have this contrived example to show what I am seeing in my code. I want to return an object which implements an interface like `A`:-

```
interface A<T extends A<T>> {
    T get();
}
```

However, when I try to return it from a method, I get this error at return type:-

`"Type parameter 'A' is not within its bound; should extend 'A<A>'"`

```
static class Simple {
    public A<A> getTheAClass() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Although using `A<?>` works, but I am not sure of the side effects.

Comment: don't you just want an interface A<T>?

Comment: @clcto has mentioned that "A doesn't extend A". That is a good point. But, what can be a good type parameter for returning from `getTheAClass`

Comment: @Leo Actually, I also want to bound the variable T. so that only subclasses/interfaces of A can be passed in as type argument.

Comment: if your method returns A, then it will just return A and its subinterfaces, isn't it?

Comment: `T extends A<T>` is recursive, so you're not able to do that. I would rethink the design of the interface.

Comment: @Luiggi It's surprising, but you can. Take a look inside Enum.java in the JDK sources some time.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza This is recursion in interface hierarchy, hence possible. Although it causes headaches.

Comment: I'm confused by what you're trying to do in Simple. Why isn't a return type of `A` good enough?

Comment: @Leo so you are saying that `A<T extends A<T>>` in interface definition ensures that whenever I return `A`, its parameter is implicitly either `A` or its subclass. Good reasoning. That ensures me safety. But I was also trying to follow the Generics guidelines of not using raw types.

Comment: @DavidConrad I was trying to avoid raw types: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it

Comment: You can make `getTheAClass()` a generic method and introduce a type variable of type `A`, for example `public <E extends A<E>> A<E> getTheAClass()`

Comment: @AsadIqbal, if you don't return A, what are you trying to enforce returning A<anything>? IMO, there's nothing to be enforced here.

Comment: I'm quite interested in this use-case myself.  Please look at question: [Ideas to enforce strict (better) type safety with a Java Interface as the parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26668135/ideas-to-enforce-strict-better-type-safety-with-a-java-interface-as-the-parame)  But every case is also unique.  Can you post a micky-mouse example of your intention: doesn't need to run if it shows what you want to achieve.